# \hrule parameters are not working

Tags: xetex, rules

In the following MWE, XeTeX prints "1pt2pt3pt" together with a rule **instead of** `\hrule` with the dimensions 1pt 2pt and 3pt. But `\rule[1pt]{2pt}{3pt}` works fine. So what is the `\hrule` command good for?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
   \hrule{1pt}{2pt}{3pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\hrule` is a TeX primitive, and its syntax doesn't allow braces.

Comment: What is most useful about `\hrule` (e.g. `\hrule hegiht0pt`) is that it acts like `\par` only wasting no space whatsoever (not even \lineskip).  I think of it as a horizontal strut.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Hi Phelype. Could you please have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550438/putting-4-pages-on-one-a4-page) question of mine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\hrule` takes keywords not braced arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
   \hrule height 1pt width 2pt depth 3pt

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

`\hrule` (and `\vrule`) is a TeX primitive, and its syntax doesn't allow braces. The syntax for `\hrule` and `\vrule` is (from Chapter 24 of *The TeXbook*):

> [image]

This means that you should use (assuming the arguments of `\hrule{1pt}{2pt}{3pt}` are `depth`, `width`, and `height`, in this order): `\hrule depth 1pt width 2pt height 3pt`.

LaTeX's `\rule[1pt]{2pt}{3pt}` is equivalent to (this requires ε-TeX for `\dimexpr`; do the calculation by hand or use a dimension register to use in Knuth's TeX):

```
\leavevmode\hbox{\vrule width 2pt height \dimexpr 3pt+1pt depth -1pt}
```