# putting 4 pages on one A4 page

Tags: xetex, pdf, pdfpages

My main interest in this question is how to modify sizes of borders of 2 pages with another 2 pages below it (so the total of 4 pages) on one A4 page.

So, can someone put 4 pages on one **A4** page suitable for immediate printing of [this](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/ConcCalcInf103109-2jiytzt.pdf) pdf (so the total of 12A4 pages should be obtained) in the way that there are borders on the l.h.s.
of size 4mm and in the middle 3+3mm (this + is because there are left and right hand side which meets in the middle of the two
snippets), and similarly 2mm on the top and bottom and 2+2 mm in the middle?

MWE of the pdfpages is required.